# .Net Core 2.0 Publish Error Angular SPA

Tags: angularjs, node.js, asp.net-core-2.0

I am having an issue when publishing my .Net Core 2.0 Angular SPA from Visual Studio 2017 Community. The site compiles and runs fine through the debugger.

When I try to publish (to ftp) I get the following error;

> The command "node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.vendor.js --env.prod" exited with code 1.

If I then run 'webpack --config ./project1/web' on the package manager console i get the error;

> webpack : Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + webpack --config ./project1/webpack.config.vendor.js
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Invalid configu...the API schema.:String) [], RemoteException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Any ideas on how to rectify this please?

I am running node 5.6.0 and the webpack in my package.json is;

```
"webpack": "3.10.0",
"webpack-hot-middleware": "2.21.0",
"webpack-merge": "4.1.1",
```